# Help reading JSON from HttpContext.InputStream

Tags: asp.net, json, xmlhttprequest, httpmodule, inputstream

I have created a HttpModule to capture requests for auditing purposes.

For Ajax requests to a web method I would like to also log the JSON data associated with the request.

E.g Request

> POST /MyPage.aspx/AddRecord HTTP/1.1
>   x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
>   Accept-Language: en-gb
>   Referer: http://fiddlerlocal:5000/AddRecord.aspx
>   Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   UA-CPU: x86
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>   Host: fiddlerlocal:5000
>   Content-Length: 287
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Cookie: .....
>   **{"id":"282aa3b5-b55f-431c-916e-60433fdb61c0","date":"8-6-2010"}**

I have tried a variety of methods to read the JSON ({"id":"282aa3b5-b55f-431c-916e-60433fdb61c0","date":"8-6-2010"}) from the HttpContext.InputStream.

Example 1:

> StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream);
>   string encodedString = reader.ReadToEnd();  **-- ReadToEnd returns an empty string**

Example 2:

> using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
>   {
>      byte[] buffer = new byte[request.ContentLength];
>      request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, request.ContentLength);
>      ms.Write(buffer, 0, request.ContentLength);  **-- The byte array contains the correct number of bytes but each byte has a value of 0 - encoded some how?** 
>      return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());  **-- doesn't do anything**
>      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());   **-- doesn't do anything**
>   }

How can I successfully extract the data from HttpContext.InputStream?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

I needed to reset the position of the stream before reading...

> request.InputStream.Position = 0;
>   using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
>   {
>   return inputStream.ReadToEnd();
>   }

Answer (score 0):

The stream can't be read as far as i know. You might  write you own handler, then buffer the stream, by reading and writing to another stream.

To parse the JSON part you might try

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(string input);
```