# How to use Json strings to connect to a server run database

Tags: c#, json

We have a project assignment in C# using visual studio, our lecturer has given us this sample code to try and connect using Json strings to build some sort of electronic Point Of Sale system.

Unfortunately I have no clue how he expects us to communicate with this server as we've been coding for like 2 months. He gave us each an access token and ID that we have to parse to the server before we can get access but I don't know what format it takes it in. For arguments sake assume the id = "epos3" and the access token = 123456789

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request =System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://ap.hbwd.in//item/{2812748393}") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
         request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        string responseContent;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }//end


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code for request with JSON text body. Note JSON is just a string here.
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://ap.hbwd.in/Products") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{\n    \"store_id\": \"72932\",\n    \"access_token\": \"A733BE122\",\n    \"cashier_id\": \"12\",\n    \"items\": [[\"1\", 1], [\"4\", 2]],\n    \"payment\": [[\"cc\", 27.35], [\"ch\", 10.00]],\n}");
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            writer.Write(byteArray);
            writer.Close();
        }
        string responseContent;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }//end
```

Comment: Is your question: I haven't tried but can you do my homework for me?  What have you tried and where are you having trouble?

Comment: We have been given 1 week to do this and I have an exam on Wednesday, my question is how am I meant to access the data when I have no idea what or how the server accepts the arguments?

Comment: It's in the code.  It accepts arguments as a json object (look at that encoding line, the string is the json object), and probably returns it the same way.  Debug, read responseContent's content.

Comment: why you dont use HTTPHandlers 
here is an example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401239/pass-jquery-json-into-asp-net-httphandler

Comment: I'm referring more to the first button method I just want to be able to get objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://ap.hbwd.in/item/2812748393") as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        string responseContent;
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                textBox1.Text = responseContent;
            }
        }//end
```