# Asp.net post JSON to ASHX for file download

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET webpage with an embedded webmethod. From jQuery I call the webmethod with ajax an pass a complex JSON object.

Can I post the same JSON object to an ashx handler and return a file (e.g. PDF)?

Comment: Yes you can do that but did you try anything ?

Comment: I have tried nothing and I am all out of ideas ;) I don't know how to call the ashx from JQuery/JS an pass the JSON as parameter. I was thinking of converting the JSON to string and pass it as url parameter.

Comment: This should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401239/pass-jquery-json-into-asp-net-httphandler

Comment: I tried this one but I need to return a PDF file as result