# Post request to .NET works in jQuery but not in Angulars $http

Tags: asp.net, jquery, angularjs, http-headers

I'm having a hard time getting Angular to do a post request that my server understands.
I either need to implement a fix server side or transform the request pre flight clientside.

**jQuery.post**

When I do a request with jQuery it responds as expected:

```
$.ajax({
        data: paramdata,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://api.example.com/api/controller',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(response) {

    angular.forEach(response.errors, function(val, row) {
        alert('jQuery says : ' + val);
    });

});
```

[image: jQuery fiddler report]

**Angular $http.post**

When I do something similar in Angular it fails with `Origin http://localhost:9000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

```
$http.post('http://api.example.com/api/controller', {
        data: {'name':'Rick James'}
    }).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;

        angular.forEach(data.errors, function(val, row) {
            alert('$http says: ' + val);
        });
});
```

[image: Angular http fiddler report]

I'm configuring my `$http` provider like this:

```
angular.module('fooApp').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    //Fix as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1454
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];

}]);
```

When I add in this line

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

it sends the data without the Acces-Control-Allow-Origin error, but the server understandably does not understand how to parse the JSON of of the application/json object.

How may I do angular $http requests that behaves more like jQuery?

***.NET Controller***

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[AllowCrossDomain]
public JsonResult JsonLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //Origin = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);

            // return Json(new { success = true, redirect = returnUrl });
            return Json(new { success = true, redirect = Session["Origin"] });
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed
    return Json(new { errors = GetErrorsFromModelState() });
}
```

We have allowed cross-domain requests wiith the AllowCrossDomain filter witch sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin, "*", Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Max-Age.

Comment: If you are using jquery in conjuction with AngularJs then do something like this `var xsrf = $.param(model); $http.post(url, xsrf);` As xbonez pointed out Angular doesn't send data like jQuery and ASP.NET doesn't play well with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is, most likely, happening, because Angular does not send data as kay-value pairs as your jQuery AJAX request does. Angular, instead, sends the data as a JSON-encoded string as part of the request stream.

You need to read in the data string from the input stream, and JSON decode it to be able to access it. You can read in the input stream like this, [taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466163/help-reading-json-from-httpcontext-inputstream)

```
request.InputStream.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(request.InputStream))
{
  return inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I'm not too familiar with asp.net, but here's an example in PHP that might illustrate the difference. When POSTing using jQuery, I can get `username` like this :

```
$username = $_POST['username']
```

But using Angular, it needs to be done like this :

```
$stream = file_get_contents("php://input"); // read input stream
$streamObj = json_decode($stream);  // json decode
$username = $streamObj->username;
```